# Device.StartTimer on Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Would code running using   Device.StartTimer run when the lock screen appears or another application is in the front ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not. The code will not execute in the background. You probably want to look at something like https://github.com/aritchie/jobs and dive more into the lifecycle of apps. A great start would be this post: https://robgibbens.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/

The options you have to run tasks in the background, depending on the platform, is limited and will require you to write platform-specific code.